# How do I print a backtrace without panicking using thiserror?

Tags: rust, error-handling, thiserror

I am running a Rust warp webserver and I need more descriptive error messages. I'd like to print a backtrace or something similar so I can tell where the error started.

I was using the `Failure` crate, but it is now deprecated so I migrated to `thiserror`.

Is it possible (without using nightly), to print a backtrace without panicking?

Comment: I also thought this was a duplicate initially, but I suspect the OP wants to know how to get the backtrace etc out of a `thiserror` object and print that, rather than just print the backtrace at some arbitrary point in the code.  Turns out that is not always possible, and not particularly well documented (IMO).

Comment: Correct - my question was specific to `thiserror`

Comment: Thiserror structs can contain a backtrace field, which can be used to print the backtrace like the suggested duplicate shows.

Comment: Since this is closed I can't give you an official answer, but here's a rough example that I put together: https://gist.github.com/mikeando/c03fd62e552ccabcdb894251b59038c7 - `thiserror` is not in the playground crates, so I can't give a useful playground link - sorry.

Comment: Hi, I’ve reopened it! This is a great answer, if you can post it I’ll choose I’ll choose it.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson this is great, but requires nightly doesn't it?

Comment: @АнатолийБугаков I think you're right. It looks like all the backtrace machinery in `thiserror` and `std::Error` are only available on nightly.

Comment: Since the question has been reopened (a few years ago, and I didn't notice!) and the playground now supports `thiserror`, I've provided the previous gist as a working answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are ways to get to the backtrace information - but it relies on what are currently "nightly only" APIs. If you're happy to use nightly and stick with `thiserror`, here's what you do... (If not then see the ASIDE at the end for other ideas).

If you're creating the error from scratch the steps are:

1. add a `backtrace: Backtrace` field to your error type.
2. set the backtrace when you create an error using `backtrace::force_captue()`

If you're creating this error due to another error and want to use its backtrace instead, then just add #[backtrace] to the `source` field where you keep the original error.

Then to get the backtrace information you can just use the `backtrace()` function on `std::Error`.

An example looks like this:

```
#![feature(backtrace)]

extern crate thiserror;

use std::backtrace::Backtrace;
use thiserror::Error;

#[derive(Error, Debug)]
pub enum DataStoreError {
    //#[error("data store disconnected")]
    //Disconnect(#[from] io::Error),
    #[error("the data for key `{0}` is not available")]
    Redaction(String),
    #[error("invalid header (expected {expected:?}, found {found:?})")]
    InvalidHeader {
        expected: String,
        found: String,
        backtrace: Backtrace,
    },
    #[error("unknown data store error")]
    Unknown,
}

pub fn explode() -> Result<(), DataStoreError> {
    Err(DataStoreError::InvalidHeader {
        expected: "A".to_owned(),
        found: "B".to_owned(),
        backtrace: Backtrace::force_capture(),
    })
}

fn main() {
    use std::error::Error;
    let e = explode().err().unwrap();
    let b = e.backtrace();
    println!("e = {}", e);
    println!("b = {:#?}", b);
}
```

This outputs something like:

```
e = invalid header (expected "A", found "B")
b = Some(
    Backtrace [
        { fn: "playground::explode", file: "./src/main.rs", line: 28 },
        { fn: "playground::main", file: "./src/main.rs", line: 34 },
        { fn: "core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once", file: "/rustc/879aff385a5fe0af78f3d45fd2f0b8762934e41e/library/core/src/ops/function.rs", line: 248 },
        ...
```

You can see a working version [in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cc3fb1dbf4a08668bf01560a6e43965d)

---

#### ASIDE

If you're not tied to `thiserror` and need to use the stable version of the compiler, you could instead use [`snafu`](https://docs.rs/snafu/latest/snafu/) which has support for backtraces using the [`backtrace` crate](https://docs.rs/backtrace/latest/backtrace/), rather than `std::backtrace`, and so works on stable.

There may also be ways to make `thiserror` work with the `backtrace` crate rather than `std::backtrace` but I've not tried that.